# How to use >=> in Scala?

Tags: scala, scalaz, kleisli

I am trying to use `>=>` (Kleisli arrow) in Scala. As I understand, it composes functions returning monads. Now I am trying it as follows:

```
scala> val f = {i:Int => Some(i + 1)}
f: Int => Some[Int] = <function1>

scala> val g = {i:Int => Some(i.toString)}
g: Int => Some[String] = <function1>

scala> val h = f >=> g
<console>:15: error: value >=> is not a member of Int => Some[Int]
       val h = f >=> g
                 ^
```

Why does not it compile ? How to compose `f` and `g` with `>=>` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two problems here. The first is that the inferred types of your functions are too specific. `Option` is a monad, but `Some` is not. In languages like Haskell the equivalent of `Some` isn't even a type—it's just a constructor—but because of the way algebraic data types are encoded in Scala you have to watch out for this issue. There are two easy fixes—either provide the more general type explicitly:

```
scala> val f: Int => Option[Int] = i => Some(i + 1)
f: Int => Option[Int] = <function1>

scala> val g: Int => Option[String] = i => Some(i.toString)
g: Int => Option[String] = <function1>
```

Or use Scalaz's handy `some`, which returns an appropriately typed `Some`:

```
scala> val f = (i: Int) => some(i + 1)
f: Int => Option[Int] = <function1>

scala> val g = (i: Int) => some(i.toString)
g: Int => Option[String] = <function1>
```

The second problem is that `>=>` isn't provided for plain old monadic functions in Scalaz—you need to use the `Kleisli` wrapper:

```
scala> val h = Kleisli(f) >=> Kleisli(g)
h: scalaz.Kleisli[Option,Int,String] = Kleisli(<function1>)
```

This does exactly what you want—just use `h.run` to unwrap.

Comment: Thank you ! Great explanation :) I don't fully understand why I need this `Kleisli` wrapper though. Is it just some _technicality_ or really principal thing ?

Comment: It's a design decision—you could definitely use an implicit class to add `>=>` to any old `A => M[B]`. I could speculate about the reasons for the decision, but that's a better question for the Scalaz mailing list.