# Kleisli Arrow with Writer in Scala. Why doesn't it compile?

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz, kleisli

This is a followup to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21660556/how-to-use-in-scala). Looks like I still did not get it. Now I am trying to compose functions that return *Writer* monad.

```
scala> val f = {x:Int => Writer("doing " + x + ";", x + 1)}
f: Int => scalaz.WriterT[scalaz.Id.Id,String,Int] = 

scala> Kleisli(f) >=> Kleisli(f)
:16: error: no type parameters for method apply: (f: A => M[B])scalaz.Kleisli[M,A,B] in object Kleisli exist so that it can be applied to arguments (Int => scalaz.WriterT[scalaz.Id.Id,String,Int])
 --- because ---
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
 found   : Int => scalaz.WriterT[scalaz.Id.Id,String,Int]
 required: ?A => ?M

              Kleisli(f) >=> Kleisli(f)
```

Why doesn't it compile ?

Comment: `argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
 found   : Int => scalaz.WriterT[scalaz.Id.Id,String,Int]
 required: ?A => ?M`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the Scala compiler expects a type shaped like `M[B]` and you give it something like `WriterT[Id, String, Int]`, it's unfortunately just not smart enough to figure out that you want to fix the first two type parameters and use the monad for `WriterT[Id, String, _]`.

There are a few possible ways to work around this limitation. The first is to define a type alias:

```
type StringWriter[A] = WriterT[Id, String, A]
```

Now you can provide explicit type parameters (in fact you could do this without the alias, but the [type lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8736360/334519) would make the line twice as long and ten times as unreadable):

```
scala> Kleisli[StringWriter, Int, Int](f) >=> Kleisli[StringWriter, Int, Int](f)
res0: scalaz.Kleisli[StringWriter,Int,Int] = Kleisli(<function1>)
```

Scalaz now provides a nicer solution, though, via Miles Sabin's ["unapply trick"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15299148/334519):

```
val ff = Kleisli.kleisliU(f) >=> Kleisli.kleisliU(f)
```

`kleisliU` is essentially just a nice version of `Kleisli.apply` that uses a new type class (named `Unapply`) behind the scenes to guide the type inference system to the right way to break apart the `WriterT[Id, String, Int]`.

Comment: Thank you ! All what you said seems very reasonable but I do not understand, I cannot just _simply_ write `f >=> g` for every `f` and `g` that return _any_ monad without all those `Kleisli`, `kleisliU` and everything ... :(( I just still do not get it.

Comment: @Michael: "The marvel is not how well the bear dances, but that the bear dances at all."

Comment: Ok, I see. All this are language limitations.

Comment: Well, I do not understand why they define `Writer` as `WriterT`. It looks like this causes the compilation problem.

Comment: Even `Writer` has two type parameters. You're only going to get type inference for `M[B]` for single-parameter generic types (`Option`, `List`, `IO`, etc.).

Comment: Aha. Now I am getting it ... That is why the type alias helps here.